# Tools for protocol simulation

Tags: protocols, simulator

My software development team has recently found itself implementing few different communication protocols for our product to achieve integration with various external products.

Although each protocol was different, the implementation process was very similar. Here are some common things that I've seen:

1. The specific communication protocol was always defined above some standard protocol (UDP, TCP/IP, Serial, CAN) and included a set of messages passing from one side to another. The structure of theses messages was predefined and described by the protocol.
2. The implementation of this protocol in our product always started from writing C++ header files based on the information provided by the protocol.
3. In order to allow early integration cycles and properly test our code we always found ourselves developing simulators that implemented our/their side of the protocol.

Here comes the question: do you know any tool that could help us to automate / simplify the processes described above?

Ideally I'd like to have a framework that allows me to do the following:

1. Define the protocol in some editor / formal language
2. Export the protocol definition to Doc/PDF in a human-readable format
3. Export the protocol definition to C++ header files (and probably to other languages)
4. Based on the protocol definition automatically (or semi-automatically) produce a simulator of both sides in the communication

I’d be thankful for any help and/or suggestion.

Comment: We have found three tools that may provide a partial answer for our needs:


1. Nash Technologies Protocol Tester
http://www.nashtech.com/home/products/npt/


2. Microsant Visual Protocol simulator
http://www.microsant.com/


3. ArcAxis Mimik Application Suite
http://www.arcaxis.com/Pages.aspx/Mimik-Application-Suite


Is someone worked with one of the above tools or knows something about them, please tell. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Colored Petri Nets; these easily model complex protocols, and there's lot of simulation tools.